# Gstreamer Serial communication between 2 devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, gstreamer, h.264, arducam

I work with Raspberry PI4 connected with 2 usb devices (ttyUSB0 , ttyUSB1) and I have h264 camera (Arducam),my camera has many ports , /dev/video0 for RAW stream and /dev/video2 for H264 stream . I send video data in first side using Gstreamer command

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! h264parse ! filesink location=/dev/ttyUSB1 blocksize=1024 max-bitrate=19000 sync=false
```

But when i try to receive and show this video in second device i bump into problem . I tried to solve it , but couldn't

I am using this command for receiving

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/dev/ttyUSB0 ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Is there any mistakes in commands , or it is possible to do using Python (opencv or other libs)? . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to encode the already encoded stream with `xh264enc` element. If you know that h264 encoded stream is available on `/dev/video2` then you can just cap the resolution and pass it to the USB device

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480 ! queue ! filesink location=/dev/ttyUSB1 blocksize=1024 max-bitrate=19000 sync=false
```

And then play the stream using

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/dev/ttyUSB1 ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480 ! h264parse ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

You probably want to read from same path as you are writing to. So I have changed the file source to `/dev/ttyUSB1` in the second pipeline.

Also, I am curious to know what kind of USB device you are using that you are able to use it as a filesink?

Comment: Thnaks for your answer!
I am using 2 simple devices (TX,RX)
The first pipeline works good, but the second gives that error.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: Filter caps do not completely specify the output format
Output caps are unfixed: video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
ERROR: Internal data stream error.
streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Freeing pipeline ...

Comment: You need to add framerate to the caps as well - better to add it to both the commands.
So your caps will look like ` ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! `